# Is there a way to detect when office online is done saving in sharepoint using graph API / sharepoint API?

Tags: office365, sharepoint-2013, azure-ad-graph-api

We have developed our own CMS. We want to be able to edit a document from our CMS in office online and after edit, download it from cloud back to our CMS. To do this, the workflow is as follows:

1. The user clicks edit on a document in our cms
2. Our webservice uploads the document to our sharepoint document library and returns the edit url
3. The edit url is opened in a new window and the user can start editing the document
4. After changing the document by the user, office online will show "Saving" in the top of the screen, and at a certain point in time it will say "Saved".
5. Meanwhile, we have a interval timer running in the browser that will call our webservice that will use the graph API to get the metadata of the document, to be more precise: the lastmodified timestamp
6. When we detect the document has changed online, we want to download it back into our CMS.

What we see, is that it takes a random period of time before the lastmodified timestamp is updated after the "Saved" message in office online. This period can be in the range of 2-60 seconds, which is aweful for our interface: the user cannot be told yet we detected the change, and because of this, the user might start doubting if everything is ok.
Also what we see, and this is even worse, is that during a undefined period of time (say 2 minutes), the last modified timestamp is updated a random couple of times! When we would download the document on the first last modified update, we would not get the actual latest version of the document, so it seems office was not done saving or synchronizing after all.

So the question is, is there a way to know when office online is actually done saving / synchronizing, so we can finally start the download from cloud to our cms and be sure it is the latest ?

I have also tried getting the metadata using the sharepoint REST API, but this has the same problems.

Thx!

Luxifur

edit:formatting.

Answer (score 0):

A work around for you.

If user click the edit in your CMS, then you can store the file version to some cache, and during this period of time we can let user download the file but need to alert the user the file being edited by someone(if the file version is in the cache, the file must be in editing). (**You can decide whether the user is notified after the files are done editing**.)

Using the interval timer running in the browser to monitor the file state. Because the files are saved are asynchronous, not absolute synchronization. So you encounter period range of 2-60 seconds is normal. Anyway, we only waiting for the corresponding notification of "Saved" appears in the browser.

After the saving done, update the file version and download the file. **If some one have opened a copy during the editing, we can alert it to download the latest version**. Finally remove the file version from the cache.

the filename is the cache key and the file version is the value, you can adjust the design

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this does not solve my problem: I still do not know when office online is done saving. So when starting polling after the end-user only made one change, I might get 1 - 5 times a changed last modified timestamp. There is no way of knowing when to assume *this* changed last modified timestamp indicates I should now download the file back to our cms.

Comment: I think you have not get my solution.  If you get 1-5 times changed, just entend the monitor time for browser. The whole solution is a whole.

Comment: There are two key points in my solution: 1. Cache fro editing file info 2. Browser Monitor service.